Ruby in VSCode, Couldn't find a workspace
I've started to learn how to use Ruby on VSCode, but I've never used VSCode before, I find it struggle to setup things
Everytime I try to debug my code, there always will be an error "Couldn't find a workspace for URI: file:///c%3A/Users/Admin/Desktop/Ruby/RubyWS or editor: [object Object]"
can someone help, thank you!
Learn how to use VSCode properly!

The question has been closed, but ultimately this is what worked for me:

Make sure you have the latest version of Ruby installed (VSCode apparently requires Ruby 3.0+).
Make sure you click Open Folder and select the folder. This apparently treats it as a "default" workspace that is automatically setup.

Hope you get it working! I know it can be super-frustrating to run across these kinds of errors ❤️

You need to make the ruby environment available in your local machine. Then you need to run the ruby. Also, you are trying to run the ruby by using the extension. which is not a good practise - not possible.

Unfortunately, this does not tell the OP how to run INSIDE of VSCode, but how to run Ruby from a command line instead.
I think the OP wants to be able to press a button in VSCode to run a Ruby file.
We're hitting the exact same issue right now. If I find an answer, I'll post here.
